# How to create minimize and maximize button in vuetify dialog box?

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to create a dialog box like the Gmail compose dialog box in vuetify and vuejs that can enable the user to minimize and maximize the dialog box and access the other component without closing the dialog box. Help me to find that solution.

Comment: please share [mcve] of your attempt